# How to send from node data to localStorage React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, reactjs, local-storage

### node

```
const LocalStorage = require ('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
localStorage = new LocalStorage('./localStorage');
localStorage.setItem('username', user.name);
localStorage.setItem('token', user.token)
```

---

### react

```
const author = localStorage.getItem('username')
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
```

In react console.log(localStorage) // {}

P.S: maybe need send from react to node GET request?

```
  fetch('/api', {
    method: 'GET'
```

Comment: `node-localstorage` just attempts to simulate the LocalStorage idea on the server. It does not save it in the browser's localStorage. What you can probably do is to send the json data `{username: user.name, token: user.token}` to the front-end (react) and then use localStorage to set the item. node-localstorage is different from browser's localStorage

Comment: How to send token from strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Assume that you are trying to make request along with the token that you have saved in `locastorage`. for that you have to add Authorization headers. like

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

fetch('https://example.com/endpoint', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': token
  }  
})
```

to get the token create a specific route like 
first you need to import
 `import jwt from 'jwt-simple';`

Then

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res,next){
   res.send({token:jwt.encode({sub:user.id,iat:timpestamp},SecretKey)});
});
```

where SecretKey is the key defined to encryption and here the userId with time is taken to generate the token

Comment: First need send token. But how send from strategy?